# How to install jdk 1.7 on CentOS 6.4

Tags: installation, centos, java

this problem makes me crazy.

I downloaded jdk 1.6 and 1.7 from Oracle Website, and extract it in

/usr/java.

and add some path information in /etc/profile.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.7"
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

and do source command.

```
source /etc/profile
```

finally when I do java -version it send below message back.

```
bash: /usr/bin/java: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've been tried 1.6 also, but it was same.

(of course, I dod chmod thing and others..)

Thanks a lot for reading, and your advices in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

OMG, I downloaded file for wrongOS.T^T